# how to add qspaceritem to qgridlayout

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have manualy created two groupboxes with many items. In one groupbox are more items than in the second and this is a layout problem. See picture:

[image]

I test inserting vertical spacer in to "Analog" section, but with no success.

Piece of code is:

```
...
groupBox2Layout = new QGridLayout;
groupBox2 = new QGroupBox();
groupBox2->setTitle("Analog");
for(int i=0; i<=15; i++)
{
    QSlider *horizontalSlider = new QSlider(Qt::Orientation::Horizontal);
    QComboBox *comboBox1 =  new QComboBox();
    comboBox1->addItems(analogPins);
    QLineEdit *lineEdit1 =  new QLineEdit("Slider " + QString::number(i));
    groupBox2Layout->addWidget(horizontalSlider, i, 0);
    groupBox2Layout->addWidget(comboBox1, i, 2);
    groupBox2Layout->addWidget(lineEdit1, i, 3);

    groupBox2->setLayout(groupBox2Layout);
}

groupBox2Spacer = new QSpacerItem(100,100, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
groupBox2Layout->
...
```

I tested

groupBox2Layout->addItem(groupBox2Spacer); 
with error:
masim.cpp:60:22: error: 'addItem' is a protected member of 'QGridLayout'
qgridlayout.h:123:10: note: declared protected here

groupBox2Layout->addWidget(groupBox2Spacer);
masim.cpp:60:22: error: no matching member function for call to 'addWidget'
qgridlayout.h:102:17: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'QSpacerItem *' to 'QWidget *' for 1st argument
qgridlayout.h:103:10: note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 3 arguments, but 1 was provided
qgridlayout.h:104:10: note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 5 arguments, but 1 was provided

Can't find another way how to add Spacer to the "Analog" groupbox... 
Can you help me?

Comment: There are `addStretch()` and `addStrut()` methods, but they are available for `QBoxLayout`. Maybe, you'd better try `QVBoxLayout`? Those pairs of widgets can be placed into `QHBoxLayout` in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 3 arguments, but 1 was provided

You have to use this public overload to add the spacer

```
void addItem(QLayoutItem * item, int row, int column, int rowSpan = 1, int columnSpan = 1, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0)
```

so you will need to specify the row and column for the spacer.